# How can I create a regular expression (regex) between 101 and 1000?

Tags: regex, expression

How can i change this regex

```
([1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]).*
```

to match values between 101 and 1000 only. The above represents the 1000 bit only?

Thanks

Comment: Just match `([0-9]+)` globally and parse to integer?

Comment: `[1-9][0-9][0-9]` This should match 100 to 1000. Your regex matches more than only 1000. Not sure how you can prevent 100 from matching.

Comment: Is this for a real-life project, or homework? If real-life, using regex for this is misguided. Convert strings to integers and use comparison operators.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but it's matching number sgreater than 1000, example data i entered  100
101
123
200
999
1000
1001
1
10
101
1001
1234
1999
2000
3000
4000
5000

Comment: Why so many dowvotes ? Just because there probably is a better solution than a regex ?

Comment: my only option is to use a regex. the software i am using only allows for regex statements to filter results and nothing else!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(10[1-9]|1[1-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|1000)$
```

should do the trick.

- `10[1-9]` Matches 101-109
- `1[1-9]\d` matches 110-199
- `[2-9]\d\d` maches 200-999
- `1000` matches 1000
- `$` matches the end of the string

RegEx Demo: http://regex101.com/r/dE8uJ1/2

EDIT: added `^` and `$` to regex to prevent wrongful middle-of-number matches

Comment: I don't think it should match 1000. "between 101 and 1000".

Comment: Well it's simple enough to modify it to not accept 101 or 1000.

Comment: Thanks for this put if you enter the following numbers you will see that it still matches numbers greater than 1000.    

1
99
100
101
123
200
999
888
1000
1001
1002
100000
100000
1000000

The range of numbers i am dealing with ranges from 1 to 1Miliion

Answer (score 0):

You could us this :

```
^(10[1-9]|1[1-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|1000)$
```

It's

```
10[1-9]
or
1[1-9]\d
or
[2-9]\d\d
or
1000
```

from end to end (the `^` and `$`)

The number of cases to test only remembers us that there are sometimes better solutions than regular expressions

Comment: Doesn't match anything ending with a `0`, except 1000.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!^100$)^[1-9][0-9][0-9]$|1000
```

This does the trick.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/6

Comment: 1000 is to be ignored.its between 100 and 1000

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^(?!100$)((?:[1-9]\d\d)|1000)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/J5yTdV_XPgnrzVwl)

Test it in Python:

```
>>> tester='\n'.join([str(e) for e in range(2000)])
>>> tgt=range(101,1001)
>>> result=map(int, re.findall(r'^(?!100$)((?:[1-9]\d\d)|1000)$', tester, re.M))
>>> tgt==result
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([1-9]\d\d|1000)
```

This should do the trick in python3.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this. This contains an explanation of what you want to do and how to do it, along with other ranges.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html