# Message template in exception c#

Tags: c#, exception, logging, kibana, serilog

I would like to create an exception where I can pass a structured message template. Is that possible? (also to log it immediately like that with Serilog)

Example on how I would like to use this:

```
throw new NotFoundException("The book {BookId} was not found", book.Id);
```

The goal is ultimately to use elasticsearch + kibana to filter out error messages. **For example** "give me all logs containing 'The book {BookId} was not found' with a range of bookid between 100 and 1000"

Comment: `throw new NotFoundException($"The book {book.Id} was not found")`?

Comment: Your example is a bit mixed up NotFoundException vs. ConflictException

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste... I'll fix that

Comment: I do not want to use an interpolated string. I want to be able to go through my logs using the template.

Comment: Then `throw new NotFoundException($"The book was not found. BookId = {book.Id}")` for easier searching. As you mentioned serilog you might want to look a inplementing a enricher. An enricher could then take the args property you have here and add that to the output to whatever log sink you use.

Comment: I'm not sure on enrichers, I'll look into that one. But for your example above, there is no way (I would think) to filter all logs for books with id between 100 and 1000. (using elasticsearch/kibana for example)

Comment: You can do that with a regular expression, see: https://regex101.com/r/D0u0lH/1  (with help from: [How can I create a regular expression (regex) between 101 and 1000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625469/how-can-i-create-a-regular-expression-regex-between-101-and-1000))

Answer (score 0):

My attempt was correct all along. To log an error using a message template you can pass exception, template and arguments.

Exception:

```
public class NotFoundException : Exception
{
   public object?[] Args { get; set; }

   public NotFoundException(string message) : base(message)
   {
       Args = Array.Empty<object?>();
   }

   public NotFoundException(string message, params object?[] args) : base(message)
   {
       Args = args;
   }
}
```

Middleware/ExceptionHandler:

```
    try {
        //Whatever
    }
    catch (NotFoundException e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, e.Message, e.Args);
    }
```

FYI, another advantage (other than filtering out logs) using this is that you can also filter out exceptions more easily when you have dynamic data in your exception message.

```
try
{
    //Do some stuff
}
catch (NotFoundException e) when (e.Message == "The book {BookId} was not found"){
    //Do some more stuff
}
catch (NotFoundException e) when (Resources.BookNotFoundTemplate.Equals(e.Message)){
    //Do some more stuff
}
catch (NotFoundException e) when (e.Args[0] is 1234){
    //Do some more stuff
}
```

Likewise for unit-testing when testing exception messages...

```
await testedMethod.Should().ThrowAsync<NotFoundException>().Where(e => e.Message == "The book {BookId} was not found");
await testedMethod.Should().ThrowAsync<NotFoundException>().Where(e => e.Args[0] is 1234);
```